# eclipse is compiling automatically on saving project . how to get rid of it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I am making a Java web app project.
On saving it, eclipse automatically compiles it and I need to close it as it's wasting my time...
Any suggestion to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Project in the Package Explorer.

Then Project >

See the screenshot below (uncheck Build Automatically)

[image]